# Selecting fields in grouping

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have data like the following inside my `DataTable`:

```
   id   vrn   seenDate
   ---  ----  --------

    1   ABC   2017-01-01 20:00:05
    2   ABC   2017-01-01 18:00:09
    3   CCC   2016-05-05 00:00:00
```

I am trying to modify the data to only show `vrn` values with the most recent date.  This is what I have done so far:

```
myDataTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("vrn")).Select(x => new { vrn = x.Key, seenDate = x.Max(y => y.Field<DateTime>("seenDate")) });
```

I need to modify the above to also select the `id` field (i.e. I do not want to group on this field, but I want to have it included in the resulting data set).

I cannot put in `x.Field<int>("id")` in the `Select()` part, as the Field clause does not exist.

Comment: And what `Id` field you want to include? For instance, `vrn` ABC has 2 id values.

Comment: @IvanStoev The one with the most recent seenDate

Comment: There are lot of questions around this with solutions in sql. Do you need a solution in Linq only, or is it ok to have the solution in sql?

Comment: @Shadow Unfortunately it has to be done in LINQ in my case as the data is already in the data table.

Comment: For example, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column

Comment: can you use `x.FirstOrDefault().id`?

Comment: @Justcode I need to specify the column name since this is a data table though.

Comment: what data you see in `x` when you debug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an equivalent of `MaxBy` method from [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ).

In standard LINQ it can be emulated with `OrderByDescending` + `First` calls:

```
var result = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("vrn"))
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Field<DateTime>("seenDate")).First())
    .Select(x => new
    {
        vrn = x.Field<string>("vrn"),
        id = x.Field<int>("id"),
        seenDate = x.Field<DateTime>("seenDate"),
    });
```

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for. Well done and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use select new like this to select anything you want from your data

```
var query = from pro in db.Projects
                select new { pro.ProjectName, pro.ProjectId };
```

Comment: Sorry I'm using cell phon to answer thus I could't use the code plugin to specify the code

Comment: Where would that go in my query?

Comment: Var query=from item in MyDataTable select new {vrn=item.Vrn}

Comment: What you are pasting is a separate query though. I need to modify my query pasted above though

Answer (score 0):

If you may have few `ids` in the same `vrn` with same max date then the following would work:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("vrn"))
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        Grouping = x, 
        MaxSeenDate = x.Max(y => y.Field<DateTime>("seenDate"))
    })
    .SelectMany(arg => 
        arg.Grouping.Where(y => y.Field<DateTime>("seenDate") == arg.MaxSeenDate));
```

It will retrun an `IEnumerable` of the original `DataRow` so you have all your fields there.

Or you can add another select to have only the fields you need.